# useContext Response react.js

Tags: reactjs, promise

Hello everyone i have a problem with my code! with useContext

here is my Request to Server:

```
import axios from "axios";

export const SearchForTracks = async (entValue, tokens) =>{

    const response = await axios.get(`https://api.spotify.com/v1/searcq=${entValue}&type=artist`{
        headers:{
            'Authorization': `Bearer  ${tokens}`
        }
    })

    return response.data.artists.items
}
```

and it's the Response i got from my request, it geives me an array of objects like this:

```
(19) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
```

and here is my changeHandler Function and useState, i want to get artists from request and pass them throw useContext to another Component

```
export const ArtistContext = createContext();   

function TopSearch() {
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false); // Open State
    const [tokens] = useContext(TokenContext) // tokens Context
    const [artists,setArtists] = useState([]) //  Artists State

    // onChange Handler for Search
    const onChangeHandler = async(event) =>{
        [event.target.name] =  event.target.value; // set value to input
        let entValue = event.target.value;
        setArtists(SearchForTracks(entValue,tokens)); // Send input Value to API and get response back
    }

return ( 
        <>
            <ArtistContext.Provider value={artists}> 
                {open ?
                    <SearchLanding />
                    :
                    null
                }
            </ArtistContext.Provider>
        </>
    );
}
export default TopSearch;
```

so when i pass data to my child Component i receive data like this:

```
Promise {<pending>}
[[Prototype]]
: 
Promise
[[PromiseState]]
: 
"fulfilled"
[[PromiseResult]]
: 
Array(19)
```

so when i want to destruct this and get data or map() on them i can't do this, it says .map() is not a function or it returnes undefined.

so what is the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SearchForTracks` is a *Promise*. You have to *await* it.

```
setArtists(await SearchForTracks(entValue,tokens));
```